# Import multi-page table from PDF as table

Tags: tables, graphics

I have a PDF document, which contains a table over multiple pages. I need to include this PDF as a single long/multipage table in the PDF document.

I tried:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm, page=1, width=\textwidth]{table.pdf} 
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm, page=2, width=\textwidth]{table.pdf} 
    \caption{Example}
\end{table}
```

The result looks as follows:

[image: Latex table]

The 2nd page of the PDF goes into the footer of the page.

A solution for multipage figures can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089881/605890

You can find a mwe here: https://github.com/boldt/latex-table

Comment: a `table` environment is a box, which can not break, just remove it

Comment: But I need it as a table; and to be listed in the list of tables. The solution from Heiko Oberdiek is already really good.

Comment: yes the first of Heiko's suggestions was what I intended by my comment:-)

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways.

### `\includegraphics` with `\captionof`

The table document is trimmed via `pdfcrop table.pdf`.

The caption is added by `\captionof`. The continued caption uses an empty optional argument of `\captionof` to avoid another entry in the list of tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\bigskip
\begingroup
  \centering
  \includegraphics[page=1, width=\linewidth]{table-crop.pdf}
  \captionof{table}{Example}
  \newpage
  \includegraphics[page=2, width=\linewidth]{table-crop.pdf}%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionof{table}[]{Example (cont.)}
  \par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]

> [image: Page 2]

### Package `pdfpages`

Multiple documents can also be included via package `pdfpages`:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{table.pdf}
```

But the placement of the caption is not so easy.

### CSV data

If you are the creator of the table, then you can save it as `.csv` file and import it in LaTeX. Example with package `csvsimple` and `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvreader[
  longtable=lll,
  head,
  table head={%
    \bfseries Name & \bfseries Value & \bfseries Text\\\hline\endhead
    \caption{Example}\endlastfoot
  },
]{test-table.csv}{
  Name=\colname,
  Value=\colvalue,
  Text=\coltext
}{%
  \colname & \colvalue & \coltext
}
\end{document}
```

And the data file `test-table.csv`:

```
Name,Value,Text
Test 1,1,A
Test 2,2,B
Test 3,3,A
Test 4,4,B
Test 5,5,A
Test 6,6,B
Test 7,7,A
Test 8,8,B
Test 9,9,A
Test 10,10,B
Test 11,11,A
Test 12,12,B
Test 13,13,A
Test 14,14,B
Test 15,15,A
Test 16,16,B
Test 17,17,A
Test 18,18,B
Test 19,19,A
Test 20,20,B
```

> [image: Result]

Advantages are more control over the table layout, page breaks, ...

Comment: I am not the creator of the table, so I don't want to tex the whole table. I like the `captionof` solution. I like to trim the pdf with latex itself `trim=2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm`. It works really good. I changes `figure` to `table`. Is there any way to have a caption on all pages? Like "Table 1", "Table 1 cont." ... whatever?

Comment: @Dennis: `\captionof` can also be used to generate the following captions, see the updated example.

Comment: first solution works definitely in the most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one because I needed it on my table list.

```latex
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Example of table.}
\label{tbl:table-crop}
\tiny
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\includegraphics[page=1, width=\linewidth]{table-crop.pdf}
\par\medskip\ABNTEXfontereduzida\selectfont\textbf{Fonte:} Myself (2022) \par\medskip
\end{table}
```